# Use ngIf checking if a string starts with certain character

Tags: angular, angular6, angular-ng-if

Is it possible to do this by using angular? I have tried both ways and none of them work.

```
<div class="card-1" [ngStyle]="{'opacity':cardNumber[0] == '4' ? '0.5' : 'none' }"></div>
```

Help

```
 [ngStyle]="{'opacity':cardNumber.startsWith('4') ? '0.5' : 'none' }">
```

Comment: Both work absolutely fine: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-hrstg5?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.html

Comment: Where is ngIf in your code?

Answer (score 3):

You might as well create a pipe for that:

```
import { Pipe, PipeTransform } from '@angular/core';

@Pipe({
  name: 'startsWith'
})
export class StartsWithPipe implements PipeTransform {
  transform(fullText: string, textMatch: string): boolean {
    return fullText.startsWith(textMatch);
  }
}
```

And use it like that:

```
<div [ngStyle]="{'opacity': ('hello' | startsWith:'he') ? '0.5' : 'none' }">
  Test
</div>
```

Here's a working Stackblitz example:
https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-nmjvu3