# Angular ngIf check if variable starts with a specified character in component html

Tags: html, angular, angular10

I currently have this:

```
<div *ngIf="name !== '@name1'>
  Show something
</div>
```

But I would like to change it to check if var name value starts with a specific character for example @.

How can I do this?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Use ngIf checking if a string starts with certain character](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51429248/use-ngif-checking-if-a-string-starts-with-certain-character)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use [startsWith](https://developer.mozilla.org/fr/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Objets_globaux/String/startsWith) method like this

```
<div *ngIf="name.startsWith('@')">
  Show something
</div>
```

And if you want to check if string doesn't start with '@' simply add '!' like `*ngIf="!name.startsWith('@')"`

Comment: Oh, this is also nice solution.

Comment: How would I say ... NOT start with? !== ?

Comment: Place an exclamation mark before a boolean statement to invert it `!name.startsWith('@')`

Comment: With the exclamation, I have edited

Answer (score 1):

You can simply use `indexOf` method to get starting index of your character and if it's 0 it means it's true else false.

Like below.

```
<div *ngIf="name.indexOf('@name1') === 0">
   it's start with @name1
</div>

<div *ngIf="name.indexOf('@name1') !== 0">
  it's not start with @name1
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

you can just add this code inside the Component :

```
export class NameComponent implements OnInit {

public isNameContainAt = false;
public name = 'name';
constructor() { }

ngOnInit() {
if (this.name.startsWith('@') == true) {
  this.isNameContainAt = true;
}

}

}
```

And then in the template :

```
<div *ngIf="!isNameContainAt">
```

Show something